# MVC site not running after deployment to production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

I have performed below steps in order:
1) Taken publish from VS for MVC site and copy it to production. 
2) I did all changes in IIS (created app, selected app pool etc.)
3) Deployed db and given rights to my user
4) Changed connection string in web.config

On production IIS,it looks like as web.xyz.com but when I run it from browser it shows blank. I have checked with developer tools too but does not show any error.

On the same server, I have another sites like web1.xyz.com with exactly similar configuration and it is working but mine one is not working.Please suggest how to investigate this further? Did I missed any step here?

Comment: looks like it is issue with site hostname. it is not able to resolve hostname I have choose. do i need to configure this anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the issue. I need to add entry in DNS